# click on first optgroup option using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<select id="my-id">
  <option>Please select option...</option>
  <optgroup label="aaa">
    <option>cccc</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

by default select drop-down has selected to "Please select option..."
I want to click on cccc optgroup option from jquery.
because by performing click event on optgroup optioption one ajax call will be there. so want to hit click from jquery please help me here!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, or what you're trying to achieve. You can set the default option by adding the `selected` attribute though.

Comment: hey can you please help me here?

Comment: You've already got several answers. What further help do you need?

Answer (score 1):

Just add "selected" to your desired option.

```html
<select id="my-id">
  <option>Please select option...</option>
  <optgroup label="aaa">
    <option selected="selected">cccc</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: hey can you please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to implement [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

```js
$("#my-id optgroup[label='aaa'] option:first").click(function(){console.log("i've been clicked");});
$("#my-id optgroup[label='aaa'] option:first").trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="my-id">
  <option>Please select option...</option>
  <optgroup label="aaa">
    <option>cccc</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: hey I have used 
jQuery("#my-id optgroup option:first").trigger("click");
but nothing happen ..... I want to click that optgroup option just like we do manually .... is that possible?

Comment: hey can you please help me here?

Comment: I believe this is what you needed after all. Why don't you try it before spamming the same comment across all the answers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly certain what you're asking for, but maybe the following will help.

HTML:

```
<select id="my-id">
  <option>Please select option...</option>
  <optgroup label="aaa">
    <option value="cccc">cccc</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#my-id optgroup[label="aaa"]  option[value="cccc"]').prop('selected', true);
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/grw67znh/

Comment: thanks for your reply .... but it is not performing click event :(
It just get selected into drop-down.
I want exactly click event which we do manually!

Comment: Sorry this code didn't help, but I'm not understanding what you're asking for.

Comment: manual clicking on that option will call ajax call .... but doing selected true or selected="selected" just set that option into drop-down ..... I want to click that option using jQuery ....

Comment: hey can you please help me here?

Comment: So, to be clear, when the page loads (or some other event is triggered), do you want the code to programmatically "click" the first option (<option>cccc</option>) in the optgroup (<optgroup label="aaa">), which will make an AJAX call? Or, do you simply want the AJAX call to be fired when the User clicks on that option?

Comment: I want programmatically   click!

Comment: Not sure if you can programmatically click and option element, but I created a new Fiddle that may work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/qvtqu7sr/